# Best way to insantiate a subclass that uses STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, instantiation, single-table-inheritance

I'm using single table inheritance in my app and I've run into a dilemma on how to best instantiate a subclass.  Say we have a class `Dwelling`, and subclasses `Apartment` and `House`.  Now `Dwelling` is associated with another class `Neighborhood`.

models/dwelling

```
belongs_to :neighborhood
```

models/neighborhood

```
has_many :dwellings
```

Let's say I have instantiated a new neighborhood as follows and I want to create a `House`

```
n = Neighborhood.new
```

Which of these is the correct method?

```
n.dwellings.build 

House.new
```

If I instantiate using the first method I must fill in the dwelling `:type`.  But with the second method I must enter the foreign key.  I also read that I should never instantiate a subclass via its parent class so that would immediately rule out `n.dwellings.build` if this advice was correct?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding

```
has_many :apartments 
has_many :houses
```

along with **:has_many :dwellings** in **Neighborhood** model will solve your problem.

```
n = Neighborhood.new
```

Now you can use

```
n.houses.build
```

or

```
h = House.new
n.houses << h
```